# Changing mapred.reduce.tasks

Tags: xml, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hdfs

In which file should I set the number of reducers and set the `mapred.reduce.tasks` parameter?

I only have the following files in my `conf` folder and none of them have this parameter:

```
ubuntu@group-3-vm1:~/conf$ ls
capacity-scheduler.xml  hdfs-site.xml  mapred-site.xml  yarn-site.xml
core-site.xml           hive-site.xml  tez-site.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Hadoop configuration properties are segregated into the following groups.

Hadoop-1.X.X:

1. core   - core-site.xml
2. hdfs   - hdfs-site.xml
3. mapred - mapred-site.xml

Hadoop-2.X.X

1. core      - core-site.xml
2. hdfs      - hdfs-site.xml
3. mapreduce - mapred-site.xml
4. yarn      - yarn-site.xml

So you want to alter the number of reducers i.e mapred.reduce.tasks. You have to keep this parameter in **'mapred-site.xml'** file.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
You can specify `mapred.reduce.tasks` into the [mapred-site.xml](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml). This will set the configuration for all the job which will ever run  on hadoop setup. In my opinion, this is not a good idea.

Ideally number of reducer are set as per the job requirement. You can use the below provided options for doing so.

---

> The number of `Reducer` for your job can be set in through command line when you run/launch the hadoop job.

```
hadoop jar <main_jar.jar> Main_class -D mapred.reduce.tasks=<number_of_reducers>
```

> Another way is, in your `Driver` class into the `Job` configuration.

```
job.setNumReduceTasks(number_of_reducers);
```

You are not required to set the property `(mapred.reduce.tasks)` in any of the configuration file. The default value is 1.

**If you are using hadoop 2**, better to use **`mapreduce.job.reduces`** instead of **`mapred.reduce.tasks`**.

Comment: Hey your answer is good, but the above question is, in which file we need to add this parameter?.

Comment: @Naga Thanks for your feedback.